How to switch windows in Python Selenium?
I'm facing below error when trying to switch windows in Python Selenium webdriver.
found more than 1 handles...
INFO: ['4294967297', '4294967308']
ERROR: Exception: NoSuchWindowException, Message: Unable to locate window: undefined
ERROR: Stacktrace:
ERROR: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:175:5

This the code snippet, I have posted the code that is after clicking that opens the new window.
    handles = base_params[self.driver_key].window_handles
    if len(handles) > 1:
        logger.info(len(handles))
        logger.info("found more than 1 handles...")
        logger.info(handles)
        base_params[self.driver_key].switch_to.window(handles[1])
        print("Switched to popup window with title:", base_params[self.driver_key].title)
    else:
        print("No popup window found")

Not sure what I'm missing here. I also posted the execute logs above.
I'm expecting the window to be switched.

it seems this window doesn't exists any more. Maybe you were running some code which replace elements in browser memory and now windows had different numbers. Oftern whey you click something then browser removes some elements from screen (and from memory) or add some elements on screen (and in memory) and this changes every thing - and it needs to get windows again. OR sometimes selenium runs too fast and it get values before browser changed elements in windows (and in memory) and later selenium use wrong values - and it needs to wait/sleep before you get new data.
